# Fancybox 3 is showing HTML content multiple times apart instead of just one big DIV with a white background

Tags: jquery, ajax, fancybox-3

I am building HTML in the Back-end code and returning the code like this:

```
sb.AppendLine(string.Format("<div style='float:left; margin:10px; width:115px; height:115px; padding:5px;'><img alt='{0}' src='{1}' style='width:100px; height:100px;'/></div>", altText, imageSource));
```

The code above would build multiple images, but I want it to display in one Fancybox parent DIV with a white background with a close button.

I did try to add a width and height attribute, but this gives each 100px x 100px image a parent which is for example 800px x 800px.

Which attribute do I need to add so that the content shows in the center of the page in only one DIV"

[image]

[image]

```
var GetHTML = data;

$('.ChildLinkFancybox').on('click', function () {
  var CategoryID = $(this).attr("id");
  var UserID = "<%=CurrentUserId%>";
  var CompanyID = "<%=CompanyID%>";
  var CurrentCustomerCode = "<%=CurrentCustomerCode%>";

  if (CurrentCustomerCode == "") {
     CurrentCustomerCode = "000-000";
  }

  var APIURL = $.fn.GetBaseURL() + 'DesktopModules/DNNCommon/API/Store/GetProductsForPubCategory?CategoryId=' + CategoryID + '&UserID=' + UserID + '&CompanyID=' + CompanyID;

$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  async: true,
  url: APIURL,
  datatype: "json",
  success: function (data) {
    var GetHTML = data;
     $.fancybox.open({                      
     type: 'html',
     content: GetHTML,
     autoSize: false,                            
     });
   },
   error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
     console.log(xhr.responseText);
   }
   });
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

The container below won't work as I need to add a container div outside the foreach loop in C# and not the View.ascx file.

```
<div class="MainPublishingCategoryLinkWrapper" id="mainWrapper">
    <%=GetPublishingCategoryListWithFancyBoxProducts()%>
</div>
```

This is the correct way to do add it, then you should just set a width and height.

```
sb.AppendLine("<div class='publishinglinksfancyboxwrapper'>");

    foreach (var product in simpleInfo)
    {
        //html being generated from server   
    }
sb.AppendLine("</div>");
```